# Trying to install react js in windows 10.but i got this error every time

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react.I installed create-react-app using npm command.After that when i executed the command create-react-app myapp it shows this error

```
Creating a new React app in C:\Users\BISWAJIT\Desktop\nodeadminuser\myreact1102020\myapp.                                                                                                                                                       

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.                                                               
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...                                                                                                                                                                             

C:\Users\BISWAJIT\Desktop\nodeadminuser\myreact1102020\myapp\react-scripts -> C:\Users\BISWAJIT\Desktop\nodeadminuser\myreact1102020\myapp\node_modules\react-scripts\bin\react-scripts. 

> core-js@2.6.11 postinstall C:\Users\BISWAJIT\Desktop\nodeadminuser\myreact1102020\myapp\node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules\babel-runtime\node_modules\core-js                                                                            

> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

> core-js@3.6.4 postinstall 
C:\Users\BISWAJIT\Desktop\nodeadminuser\myreact1102020\myapp\node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules\core-js                                                                                                        

> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"                                                                                                                                                                                             

+ cra-template@1.0.1                                                                                                    
+ react-dom@16.12.0                                                                                                     
+ react@16.12.0                                                                                                         
+ react-scripts@3.3.1                                                                                                   
added 1556 packages from 746 contributors in 762.12s                                                                    
Missing dependencies in package.json
```

here is my image link https://i.stack.imgur.com/UeVg2.png

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed **NodeJS** on your computer, we usually just need to run the command

```
> npm install -g create-react-app
> npx create-react-app my-app
> cd my-app
> npm start
```

after your run the command. react should have been successfully installed. i hope this helps :)

Comment: wait.., from starting the creat-react-app installation has gotten an error ??